# SFTP very slow speeds and uses only single core

Tags: ssh

I've been having interesting problem. I have sftp server on Raspberry Pi (3B) and it was working fine (upload ~10Mb/s), then I've noticed it dropped to ~1Mb/s and stayed around that for 6 months. When file is being uploaded, `htop` shows that only one core is being used (at 100%), while others sits idle. After upgrading to Raspberry Pi 4 (2GB) this weekend I was surprised that `sftp` upload went to ~30Mb/s and ALL cores were being used when files were being uploaded. Being happy and all, I was thinking that hardware was at fault, but today same behavior returned (upload ~2Mb/s, one core used). Anyone has any idea what could cause this behavior? I'm using Raspbian with latest updates. After receiving Rpi 4 I've just swapped SD Card from my old one and it worked out of the box (did `apt dist-upgrade ofc`).

Edit:
After fresh Raspberry Pi OS installation it was back to normal speeds, and `htop` showed all cores being used when transferring. However a week it dropped to ~3Mb/s. Seems that its not sftp that uses all CPU, but `ksoftirqd`, which takes up to 99% CPU.

Comment: well ... sftp has only ever used one core for me - about 2.5% of one core ... and it maxes out my upload (about 30Mb/s)

Comment: That's what puzzles me, it did use all cores to ~25% two days ago, and today it only uses one at 100% and speed is ~2.5Mb/s. No updates or turn on/offs in the meantime.

Comment: odd that it's using so much cpu ... mine is 1 x 2.5% - yours is either 4x25 or 1x100 (essentially the same, but not) ...